# SharePoint online library lookup column issue

Tags: powerapps-forms

I have created a lookup column in my document library to get the data from another SharePoint list. Because of the 5000 records lookup limitation, I have used the Power Apps filter option (Delegation functionality) to get data from the SharePoint list.Everything works fine and I can save data in SharePoint document library, until I make the ****SelectMultiple** to **true** in Power Apps, then I cant save the record in the library.

The below script is the delegation functionality to get data from another list:
`Filter('FileService_neats.Alf', StartsWith(FileName, DataCardValue4.SearchText))`

[image]
[image]

Kind Regards